# Can you replace displayed text with something else in command window?

Tags: shell, sed, string, replace, text

I am trying to manage user accounts. They are basically just numbers, but I would rather see user last names on the screen. Is it possible to automatically replace displayed text with something else?

For example when I go to `/home/users` and type `ls-al`, can I somehow see:

```
Smith
Johnson
Adams
Andrews
```

instead of

```
001 
002 
003 
004
```

or can I somehow see both?

```
001 "Smith"
002 "Johnson"
003 "Adams"
004 "Andrews"
```

Comment: what youre asking is impossible.

Comment: Why aren't your userids already alphanumeric? Do you have a mapping of user numbers to names?

Comment: Can you show the actual output of "ls -al" and a example of what's in /etc/passwd? Are your usernames numerical? If so, you'll likely have to create something custom to do that.

Comment: @roaima I work at a big place and the user accounts are handled by a different group who decided on numbers for whatever reason. I have a mapping for my team's numbers-to-names that I keep at my desk. It would just be a lot more efficient if I could automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you named all your users by number, and you want to see their last names.

Where are their last names stored? in other words, you need to make some kind of correlation between the names and numbers; where is the source of that information?

Assuming you have some master list that correlates NUMBER to LAST-NAME, then you could set up an `ls` frontend for your self. For example:

If you have a file "usernames.list":

```
001 Smith
002 Johnson
003 Adams
004 Andrews
```

Then you can write a loop that re-implements `ls` but with correlation between your list and the keys it finds in /home:

```
for DIR in * ; do fgrep ${DIR} /path/to/usernames.list ; done
```

Which would print:

```
001 Smith
002 Johnson
003 Adams
004 Andrews
```

If you userlist is more complex than those key/value pairs, you can use `cut` to parse the info as you desire.

For the record, this is not the standard way of managing users.

Users on a POSIX system already have unique identifiers (the User ID, see the `id` command) so naming all your users incrementally from 001 is definitely not ideal.

Comment: Yeah as I posted above this decision was made long before me, and I have no actual control over the situation. I am just trying to make my life easier when I go to look in a user's directory so I do not have to carry around my sheet of numbers-to-names. Re-implementing ls seems like the best option so far.